# App Store Featured Summary View design

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

How has Apple designed the View that you get when you look at an app summary in the Featured section of the App Store ( http://i44.tinypic.com/20gfgjr.jpg ) ?

There seem to be 2 ways of doing it:

1. Using a UITableView and then creating custom UITableViewCell items for each row
2. Using a UIScrollView and then adding UIView subviews

Any recommendations as to what's the best way of doing this in Interface Builder / Xcode?

Comment: I thought that was done in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is made with several views within a UIScrollView. Not a big deal – imho.